# Class 'Form' not found (View: /path/to/laravel/resources/views/posts/create.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-5, laravelcollective

I am trying to use Forms but keep getting this error:

> Class 'Form' not found

and

> Class 'Form' not found (View: /path/to/laravel/resources/views/posts/create.blade.php)

my **create.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h1>Новая новость</h1>
    <hr>
      {!! Form::open(['route' => 'posts.store']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('title',"Заголовок:") !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}

        {!! Form::label('body', "Текст:") !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('body',null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}

        {!! Form::submit('Сохранить', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top:10px;')) !!}
      {!! Form::close() !!}
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I add all needed lines and executed the commands according to the manual at [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#installation)

Providers:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

Alias:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Begin by installing this package through Composer. Edit your project's `composer.json` file to require `laravelcollective/html`.

   ```
   "require": {
       "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0" 
   }
   ```
2. Next, update Composer from the Terminal.
3. Next, add your new provider to the providers array of `config/app.php`:

   ```
   'providers' => [
       'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'
   ],
   ```
4. Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of `config/app.php`:

   ```
   'aliases' => [
       'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
       'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade'
   ],
   ```